# Spring boot war with active profile using gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I am using Gradle to build my spring boot project into a war file. I want to build different flavors of the war file using different profiles. I have the following in my Gradle file

```
tasks.register("bootRunDev") {
    group = "application"
    description = "Runs the Spring Boot application with the dev profile"
    doFirst {
        tasks.bootRun.configure {
            systemProperty("spring.profiles.active", "dev")
        }
    }
    finalizedBy("bootRun")
}

tasks.register("bootWarDev") {
    group = "application"
    description = "Runs the Spring Boot application with the dev profile"

    doFirst {
        tasks.withType<JavaExec> {
            systemProperty("spring.profiles.active", "dev")
        }
    }

    finalizedBy("bootWar")
}
```

the `./gradlew bootRunDev` command works but I am struggling to inject it into the war file. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I am now trying to replace the war file application.properites with

```
tasks.register("bootWarDev") {
    copySpec {
        from("src/main/resources") {
            filter<ReplaceTokens>(Pair("activeProfiles", "dev"))
            println("run")
        }
    }
}
```

but this is not working either

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What do you mean by 'inject it into the war file'? `bootRun` runs the application. You set the env property `spring.profiles.active` to `dev`, which means the `dev` profile will be active. What's the point of setting the env property when generating a WAR, though?

Comment: I want to have `spring.profiles.active = dev` run when the war file runs. But your question I think helps me understand the issue. That `systemProperty` is setting an env during run and not packaging it in the jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue I was using maven replacement needed to use Gradle replacement with `spring.profiles.active=${activeProfile}` and define this value in the project.properties